# FTDI driver library fail on run

Tags: c++, netbeans, shared-libraries

4 to program a Raspberry Pi B with Raspian Wheezy. My pi has custom daughter board with an FTDI usb/serial chip FT231X. I located a driver for this device ( FTD2xx.1.1.12 ) which comes with a few example programs. As per the docs I installed the drivers ( .a and .so ) to /usr/loca/lib and then ran one of the example programs. This was done using the SSH client ie not from Netbeans. There o build errors and the program ran without errors. Now when I try and include the static library in my Netbeans build it builds OK but when I attempt to run ( debug or release build ) it does not run and returns an error "error while loading shared libraries:libftd2xx.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. RUN FAILED ( exit value 127, total time 203ms )". Firstly why is it looking for the shared library when I linked in the static .a library in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in plain c trying to compile one of the examples.
I was doing

```
gcc main.c -o ftdiTest -lftd2xx
```

but ran into the same error.
using the `rpath` flag compiling solved the problem:

```
gcc main.c -o ftdiTest -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
```

I'm not if it's actually needed, but setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib` might help.

The executable will need be run with `sudo` and `ftdi_sio` and `usbserial` drivers need to be unloaded if present before running the app using libftd2xx. Here's a quote from the Readme on it:

> If the message "FT_Open failed" appears:
>       Perhaps the kernel automatically loaded another driver for the 
>       FTDI USB device.
>
> ```
> `sudo lsmod`
>
> If "ftdi_sio" is listed:
>     Unload it (and its helper module, usbserial), as follows.
>
>     `sudo rmmod ftdi_sio`
>     `sudo rmmod usbserial`
>
> Otherwise, it's possible that libftd2xx does not recognise your 
> device's Vendor and Product Identifiers.  Call FT_SetVIDPID before
> calling FT_Open/FT_OpenEx/FT_ListDevices.
> ```

This should work in c++ too (I've used the same in an [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/download/) project)

Also, I remember having some issues with the library on Raspberry PI1 (armv6) and emailed FTDI support. They supplied a recompiled library which worked. The same library works on Raspberry PI2(armv7)